# .htaccess rewrite rule 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess

I've these lines in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/admin/(.*)$ I:/xampp/htdocs/dev/systems/cms/$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/admin(.*)$ I:/xampp/htdocs/dev/systems/cms/$2 [N]  
AliasMatch ^(.*)/tinymce/(.*)$ I:/xampp/htdocs/dev/tinymce_4.0.16/$2
```

I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error due to these.
It should be like http://example.com/mysebsite/admin or http://example.com/mysebsite/admin/
should locate to dir located at /dev/systems/cms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `AliasMatch` in an htaccess file. Also, are you sure you want the `I:`, assuming it's "drive I". You can just use the path relative to the document root: `/dev/systems/cms/$2`.

Also make sure mod_rewrite is loaded.